# Moving a sprite using keyboard

Tags: sprite, sfml

I'm trying to move `playerSpaceShip` by keyboard. The function is changing its position (checked in the console by getcoordinates()) but it's not displaying it on the screen(sprite is not moving). Anyone can figure out why?

player.cpp

```
void player::movePlayer(sf::Vector2f distance)
{
    playerSpaceShipSprite.move(playerMoveSpeed * distance.x, playerMoveSpeed * distance.y);
}

void player::render(sf::RenderTarget* target)
{
    target->draw(playerSpaceShipSprite);
}
```

game.cpp

```
void game::update()
{
    while (window->isOpen())
    {
        while (window->pollEvent(sfEvent))
        {
            if (sfEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window->close();

            playerMovement(sfEvent);
        }
    }
}

void game::renderPlayer()
{
    if (Player)
        Player->render(window);
}

void game::render()
{
    window->clear();

    renderBackground();
    renderPlayer();
    renderBlueAlien();

    window->display();
}

void game::playerMovement(sf::Event sfEvent)
{
    if (sfEvent.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed)
    {
        switch (sfEvent.key.code)
        {
        case sf::Keyboard::Left:
            {
                Player->movePlayer(sf::Vector2f(-1,0));
                std::cout << "Left key pressed\n";
                break;
            }

        case sf::Keyboard::Right:
            {
                Player->movePlayer(sf::Vector2f(1, 0));
                std::cout << "Right key pressed\n";
                break;
            }

        case sf::Keyboard::Up:
            {
                Player->movePlayer(sf::Vector2f(0, -1));
                std::cout << "Up key pressed\n";
                break;
            }

        case sf::Keyboard::Down:
            {
                Player->movePlayer(sf::Vector2f(0, 1));
                std::cout << "Down key pressed\n";
                break;
            }

        case sf::Keyboard::Space:
            {
                std::cout << "Space key pressed\n";
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}

void game::run()
{
    while (window->isOpen())
    {
        render();
        update();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if instead of showing all the code, you showed only the parts that have to do with your problem...

Comment: Sorry, now it should be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void game::update()` has `while (window->isOpen())` at the start.

This means that the update function never returns back to `void game::run()`, where your second `while (window->isOpen())` statement is, and since it never returns to there, `void game::render()` never gets called again.

The player is moving, but the screen is not updating to show the player moving. Getting rid of `while (window->isOpen())` in `void game::update()` solves the problem.

I solved this using a debugger, setting a breakpoint inside `void player::movePlayer(sf::Vector2f distance)`, and stepping through the code until I came across the problem.